# Unable to log into a valid account after trial expired

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This might be really basic but I can't figure out how to log into my valid Photoshop account.

Previously was on a different trial account which has expired. Fair enough.

But I want to log out and log back into a paid account. Simply not able to.

Keep getting the following pop which blocks me from clicking anything on the Photoshop app.

[image]

As can see, there is nothing in here for me to log out. If I close this pop up, photoshop closes along with it.

Clicking on `Buy Now` asking for credit card details. Again, no way to log out.

Clicking on `see all plans` leads to browser adobe page. I am not even signed in there.

I have actually uninstalled and reinstalled Photoshop, and it is recognising my log in
and back to square one.

Could someone help advice how I could get out of this. Quite maddening and insane design from what I see.

Comment: [This](https://helpx.adobe.com/manage-account/kb/stop-creative-cloud-trial-mode-after-purchase.html) should help

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry it doesn't. Mine is showing trial expiry on an account which is indeed expired and I am not renewing it. I want to be able to switch to another account which is not possible currently.

Comment: [Try](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/Labs/cleaner.html) their cleaner tool.  If you then reinstall Adobe Photoshop, it should require you to login into an account.  Be sure you are downloading it fresh, from the account, which has a license.  There is a small possibility the account is linked to the installer.

Comment: The Adobe CC 'menu bar' app should forget after a reboot - but it should also have a button to just sign out, as in @Ramhound's link.